# Python3: Connect to Remote Postgres Database with SSL

Tags: database, python-3.x, postgresql, ssl, psycopg2

I am in the process of setting up a remote PostgreSQL database.  The server is running CentOS 7 and PostgreSQL-9.5.  Currently, I am testing whether users can query the database.  To this end, I have the following:

```
import psycopg2

host    = 'server1'
dbname  = 'test_db'
user    = 'test-user'

sslcert = 'test-db.crt'
sslmode = 'verify-full' 
sslkey  = 'test-db.key'


dsn = 'host={0} dbname={1} user={2} sslcert={3} sslmode={4} sslkey={5}'.format(host, dbname, user, sslcert, sslmode, sslkey)

conn = psycopg2.connect(dsn)
```

The connection times out with the following error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
    Is the server running on host "server1" (xx.xx.xx.xx) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have tried several things (given below).  I'm trying to pin down on which side the problem exists: the Python end or the database configuration:

- Is the Python syntax correct?
- Where can I find documentation concerning the [DSN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_source_name) arguments, such as `sslmode`, `sslcert`, and `sslkey`?
- Is there a different package better suited for this kind of connection?
- What other questions should I be asking?

---

I have checked the following:

1. 'server1' was entered correctly and the IP address returned by Python corresponds
2. All other arguments are spelled correctly and refer to the correct object
3. Postgres is currently running (`service postgres-9.5 status` shows "active")
4. Postgres is listening on port 5432 (`netstat -na | grep tcp` shows "LISTEN" on port 5432)
5. SSL is running for my table (`psql -U username -W -d test-db -h host` returns `SSL connection (protocol: TLSAv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)`
6. `user=test-user` has been added to postgres as a Superuser

My understanding is that `psycopg2` is the appropriate package to use nowadays.  I have scoured the [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html) and don't find much information regarding SSL connections.  I found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191456/postgres-python-multiple-ssl-connections) which talks about SSL connections using `psycog2`, but I can't match some of the syntax to the documentation.

In the Python script, I have tried the following in all 4 combinations:

1. Use `sslmode='require'`
2. Use absolute paths to `test-db.crt` and `test-db.key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have presented yourself with a [False Dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma).  The problem does not lie solely between Python and the database configuration.  There exist other entities in between which may cause a disconnect.

---

> - Is the Python syntax correct?

Yes.  The syntax is described in the [`psycopg2.connect()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect) documentation.  It has the form:

```
psycopg2.connect(dsn=None, connection_factory=None, cursor_factory=None, async=False, **kwargs)
```

where the DSN ([Data Source Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_source_name)) can be given as a single string or as separate arguments:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dsn="dbname=test user=postgres password=secret")

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", user="postgres", password="secret")
```

---

> - Where can I find documentation concerning the DSN arguments, such as     sslmode, sslcert, and sslkey?

Note that as DSN arguments, they are not part of the `psycopg2` module.  They are defined by the database, in this case Postgres.  They can be found in the chapter on Database Connection Control Functions, under the [Parameter Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) section.

---

> - What other questions should I be asking?

Perhaps,

*Is there anything between the host (the PostgresSQL server) and the client (the local Python instance) which could prevent communication?*

One answer to this would be "the firewall."  This turned out to be the problem.  Postgres was listening and Python was reaching out.  But the door was closed.