# Run sql file using python's psycopg2 by passing parameters

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a requirement to execute postgres sql script having only a CREATE TABLE statement using python's **psycopg2** (http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute) using below command.

```
cursor.execute(open("create_table.sql", "r").read())
```

But I want to pass database name as parameter to the above sql file. If no parameter is passed it will execute default database. Is there a way to achieve the same using psycopg2.

Comment: instead of calling the .sql file you can just copy and paste the actual SQL and pass it into the cursor.execute

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the database to connect to using [`connect(dbname=)](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html):

```
from psycopg2 import connect
conn = connect(user='...', dbname='...', host='...', password='*****', port=5432)
```

You [can't change the "current" database in Posgres dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719674/change-database-postgresql-in-python-using-psycopg2-dynamically), like in some other RDBMSes that support `DATABASE xxx` or `USE xxx`.

If you have placeholders in the SQL query that you want to be filled with a specific values, use simple string interpolation, i.e. [`template_string.format()`](https://pyformat.info/#simple) or an advanced templating engine like [jinja](https://palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/).